# Gradle Selenium Project failing on Azure Pipeline

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines, ui-automation

Very new to creating Azure build pipeline for a Gradle, Selenium project using Java for UI automation. I am using a Hosted Azure Agent pool which is  windows-latest.

I have configured my Gradle tasks and is working as expected, however, when executing the tests/pipeline , it fails with a *'NoSuchElementException'* but locally it works fine with/without headless mode.

Please see below YAML and if anyone can please assist.

```
 pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: Gradle@1
  displayName: 'gradlew build'
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MYPROJECT/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: MYPROJECT
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'MYPROJECT E2E Tests'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*.jar'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `NoSuchElementException` typically occurs when Selenium is unable to locate an element on the page. Since the test is working on local machine, may i know if your local environment is same OS like windows-2022? If possible, you can set your local machine as self-hosted agent of your devops for a check. Please also share some error log snippet in the statement. In addition, it's recommended to take a screenshot at the point of failure to get a visual understanding of what’s happening at the time of the exception.